# makeSceneTransitionAnimation causes black screen after rotation on Android 11 and up

Tags: android, animation, transition

A black screen is caused after using a shared element transition. This is how I reproduce this bug:

1. Start the detail activity with `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`.
2. Rotate the screen.
3. go back to the original Activity by using the back gesture (or button).

[image: Black screen bug]

The code is pretty straightforward, but here it is:

In the first screen, OverviewActivity:

```
override fun onPictureClicked(view: View, picture: Picture, position: Int) {
    startActivity(
        GalleryActivity.createIntent(this, position),
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this,
            view,
            view.transitionName
        ).toBundle()
    )
}
```

In the second screen, GalleryActivity I make sure that the transitionName is set on the correct views. The full project can be checked out here https://github.com/nos-digital/imagin/tree/master/example.

This code works fine on Android versions below version 11, but from Android 11 this causes a black screen after a screen rotation. The only way to exit the black screen is to use multitasking or wait for an unknown amount of time.

I can consistently reproduce this bug on the Google Pixel 3, but also on other physical devices. I've also reproduced it on the Android 11 and Android 12 emulator, but here it is less consistent.

I would like to know how I can prevent this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to rour activity style and the problem will be resolved:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```